# npm install node-oracledb fails

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

I want to connect the oracle db via node js. For this, I tried to install node-oracledb module.

$ npm install oracle/node-oracledb#v3.1.2

This throws below error messages.

> > oracledb@3.1.2 install C:\Users\Desktop\WebApp\node-oracle-db\node_modules\oracledb
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> C:\Users\Desktop\WebApp\node-oracle-db\node_modules\oracledb>if not
>   defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild ) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find
>   Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable. gyp
>   ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
>   gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21) gyp ERR!
>   System Windows_NT 10.0.14393 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\Desktop\WebApp\node-oracle-db\node_modules\oracledb gyp ERR!
>   node -v v9.5.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN
>   oracle-db@1.0.0 No description npm WARN oracle-db@1.0.0 No repository
>   field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! oracledb@3.1.2
>   install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the oracledb@3.1.2 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-09T06_36_44_005Z-debug.log

I dont understand why do I need to have python dependency to connect with oracle db? and how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is built using GYP which uses python. I think that is why you are getting this error. Although to run Nodejs apps you do not need python at all. Maybe this would be a requirement for this particular package. You are specifying a version of node oracle-db which needs python to be installed.

You can run the following to resolve your issue

```
npm install oracledb
```

This should not give you the error you are facing.

If this does not work you can follow the below

You can run the following to resolve the issue you are running into.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

This is going to install python on your system.

Then you can install gyp globally

```
npm install node-gyp
```

Then maybe you can install the specific version you are looking for node-oracledb

Comment: I have installed windows-build-tools and node-gyp as you said. When I run `npm install oracle/node-oracledb#v3.1.2`, below error is coming:   **gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)**

Comment: You need to run this as administrator `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Comment: You can also try to install `Visual Studio 2015 Redistributable` and then you can do `npm install oracledb`.

Comment: Yes, I dont have the administrator permission and the powershell didnt start after windows-build-tools module installation.    windows-build-tools  +1s
Please restart this script from an administrative PowerShell!  Is there any way to install it without Administartive permission?

Comment: Then try this `install Visual Studio 2015 Redistributable` and then you can do `npm install oracledb`. This is the link `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads`

Comment: Does the package version available for visual studio 2015 Redistributable? As I don't have the administartor rights to install the executable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191601/discussion-between-nandy-and-apoorv).

Answer (score 0):

to connect the oracle db via node js,run

npm install oracledb